# Software for virtual midi device?

Tags: piano, keyboard, midi

I have software that supports input from a midi device (Plugging a keyboard into pc to record MIDI audio).

I have recorded a few MIDI files on my keyboard, but I don't have the keyboard anymore.

Is there any software out there that will take the MIDI files and output them like a keyboard does, into the other software that I want to get the midi to?

Comment: Just connect the output of any MIDI player to the sequencer's input. Or are you using Windows?

Comment: @CL. I'm using Windows :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. I downloaded loopMIDI and created a virtual port, then I used PLWMidiMap.cpl (Google search it, it's everywhere) to set the default MIDI device.

Don't try using Windows Media Player because it uses the Windows MIDI device no matter what, it seems.

Use nearly any MIDI editor/karaoke program and it seems to work.